# Particular ASP.NET page losing one (and only one?) session variable

Tags: asp.net, session, postback, webforms

I maintain a small financial site. Part of this site allows certain users to perform a bank account reconciliation, clearing lines that have been entered that show up on bank statements.  This particular page has been causing me a few headaches, as, seemingly at random, when a user submits the reconciled data or even just changes the account and date they are working with, the site will lose the ClientId they are working with.  This is, at best, mildly annoying; at worst, a lot of time is wasted, as all the lines they have just checked off have to be rechecked.

ClientId is stored in Session, so my first thought is that the Session is being lost or the Application is being recycled. However, only the ClientId Session variable (which is stored as "ActiveClient") is lost; other things like PortalId remain in place (and this is actually used to recover from what would otherwise be a serious error on the site), so that's not the issue. Then I thought that because the page submitted so much data on postback (I had to raise `MaxHttpCollectionKeys` twice for this page, it's now at 5000, though I recently changed how data is passed to cut the number of keys in half). However, this isn't the issue, either, because the error reports I'm getting also include submissions with only a few dozen keys or just a handful when they're changing the date/account being worked with.

It happens at different times, it doesn't happen every time (as a percentage of page submissions I'd say it's about 5-10%), and the only thing that seems even to be a constant across all errors is that they're from FireFox and Chrome, not Internet Explorer. However, our office uses both of those predominantly; IE is only used when staff encounters a site that *must* use it. I've asked one of my co-workers to try switching to IE, but I'm still trying to figure out other leads in the meantime.

The page is set up with two ListViews, one for Credits and one for Debits. They display one line for each transaction detail line in the financial system, which lists brief information about the transaction and gives the user the option to mark it as cleared (or, if recalling a previous reconciled statement, mark it as uncleared).

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class='<%# UseFutureDateClass(Eval("TrxDate")) %> <%# Container.DisplayIndex  % 2 == 1 ? "alt" : "" %>'>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="ClearLine" runat="server" Checked='<%# IsCleared(Eval("DateCleared")) %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="IdentSet" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("NRecord") + "," + Eval("LineNo") + "," + IsCleared(Eval("DateCleared")) %>' />
        </td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="TrxDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TrxDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="HeaderReference" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HeaderReference") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="VendorInfoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("VendorInfo.VendorName") %>' /></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
        <td class="money">
            <asp:Label ID="Amount" runat="server" Text='<%# FormatInvertMoney(Eval("Amount")) %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

That first `<td>` contains the information POSTed on form submit for each line.  Once submitted, the page will parse out the IdentSet and take action only if the line was previously cleared and is now not, or vice versa. From there it will update the financial files to mark the line as cleared or uncleared; if all updates are successfully, it marks the account as having been reconciled on the given date for the period relevant for the given date.

I can post more of the code if someone believes it will be helpful; however, as I said earlier, this issue also happens when users just change the account and date, so I don't believe the issue is in the code itself. For reference, here's the code for the ActiveClient property, maintained in a static class called "Working":

```
public static String ActiveClient {
    get {
        String s = (String)HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveClient"];
        return s ?? String.Empty;
    }
    set { HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveClient"] = value; }
}
```

**tl;dr: One, and only one, page will sometimes lose one, and (apparently) only one, session variable on submission, and I can't figure out why or how to stop it.**

Comment: I should also note that I do use Javascript on the page to sort by certain columns and to hide/show lines depending on dates, but none of these affect the actual submitted data.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveClient"].ToString()

Comment: This is going to be a tough one...sessions are cookie based, so maybe something is intermittently munging your cookies? (Something similar happened to me this morning but corrected itself before I had a chance to get in and debug it)

Comment: @Tim: I had wondered about that, myself, but I'm not that familiar with cookies aside from the basic setting/getting, and certainly not when it comes to ASP.NET Sessions.  Is there, perhaps, a better way to store this kind of information? Failing that, is there any way to test for that kind of thing? I can't recreate the issue on my own PC (stupid Heisenbug.)

Comment: Also, I only use four or five session variables over the entire site, and don't explicitly do anything with Session on the page in question aside from accessing the property shortcuts like the one I showed in the post. I know that browsers have a max Cookies-per-site limit; could something on the page be creating more session/cookies and somehow pushing out only the ActiveClient?

Comment: Why is this a static property?

Comment: It's inside a static class, where the entire class is just shortcuts to various Session properties and functions that modify then return those session properties.

Comment: You've got several options for preserving session - the default which you're using (I believe it plants corresponding server/client cookies), SQL Server, URL based, and disabling session state. Each has its own advantages/disadvantages and would require you recoding if you move away from the default. Does anyone monitor your network? You're probably going to need some help with this one.

Comment: No one that I'm aware of. Should I look into handling this a different way, rather than trying to fix what I have now? Perhaps if I rebuild the page from scratch I can manage to dodge whatever is causing this.